How much are you obligated to eat on erev yom kippur?
There's a chiyuv to eat on erev yom kippur. How much does one have to eat?
If he eats k'zais or k'grogeres he did his chiyuv and he can fast the rest of the day?
It's not logical to say he has to be eating the whole day non-stop, or keep eating until he's always full.
There's a kiyum mitzva the more you eat, it's like saying more of haggada on pesach and you're mishubach?
Or it's kiyum mitzva like the mitzva of eating matza all 7 days of pesach?
Or you look into the reason for the mitzva and that would change the chiyuv how much you need to eat?

"How much are you obligated to eat on erev yom kippur?" (The question tile.) Based on Rashi on Berakhot 8b, you should eat and drink enough to prepare yourself for the fast on Yom Kippur itself. I'm guessing that would change from person to person.

It's important to be happy on Yom Kippur.

@TamirEvan so you have to keep on eating as long as it helps? Or if it helped you're patur? Which a czais would suffice, that it helped u fast in a minute way... its chiddush reason of mitzva goes into shiur. If mishloach manos is to be marbe reyos, no one says u have to give differently based on all the factors of making that person happy... etc
